# How to get all jar paths used by OSGi?

Tags: java, osgi

I want to get all jar paths that I can search .class file in these jars. I wrote a function to search all the jars under App main folder but encountered a problem -- some jar bundles are existed but out of date and not used by OSGi, ex. xxxx_1.0.0.jar and xxxx_1.2.0.jar are both existed, but only 1.2.0 are used by OSGi. If I search in main folder, are of them will be in the result list.

So is there a way to get all the jar files which used by OSGi? Then I can filter out the jar files which not used.
Thanks

**Added:**
I tried to use this way to get all the Bundles absolute URL, but failed:

```
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
Bundle[] bundles = com.ibm.director.services.storage.debugtool.Activator.context.getBundles();
for (Bundle bundle : bundles) {
    java.net.URL url = bundle.getClass().getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation();
    sb.append("File:" + url.getFile() + ", Path:" + url.getPath() + "\n");
}
```

But hundred times of following output repeated:

```
File:/opt/ibm/director/lwi/runtime/core/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.osgi_3.4.3.R34x_v20081215-1030-RCP20120203-1500.jar
File:/opt/ibm/director/lwi/runtime/core/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.osgi_3.4.3.R34x_v20081215-1030-RCP20120203-1500.jar, 
File:....
```

The number of used bundle is: 588, it might be correct, and we can get absolute Bundles path from the API but why they are all the same? How can I get the real path?

Comment: Can you explain what you want to achieve? What do you want to search for in the class files and why?

Comment: @Christian Schneider I want to decompile the runtime .class which classname is input by user. The way I implement is to collecte all the jars in OSGi environment and serach this class. Actually both xxx_1.2.0 and xxx_1.0.0 contains this file but only xxx_1.2.0 is used. I want to only decompile the used one.

Comment: I think I remember you had a similar question some time ago. In OSGi the same class name can come from different bundles and so different versions can be used at the same time. So if you want to know the source of a class then you need to also specify the bundle/classloader that sees the class. From there you can find out from the package wiring from which jar the class was loaded.

Comment: @Christian Schneider, can you check my added information and question? thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`BundleContext#getBundles()` gives you all bundles. You can then compare symbolic names and versions. However just because you have both xxxx_1.0.0.jar and xxxx_1.2.0.jar that doesn't mean that xxx_1.0.0.jar is unused. There might be some other bundles present that require xxx_1.0.0.jar. Likewise just because a bundle isn't started doesn't mean it won't be started later. You do *not* want to reimplement the OSGi resolver. If you want to clean up a repository I would suggest you use an application provided by the vendor of the repository like GC Application in p2.

Comment: Agreed. I'd guess that the problem you're trying to solve has either already been solved or is the wrong problem.

Comment: @Philippe Marschall, can you check my added information and question? thank you.

Comment: I see you're using Equinox, in this case I recommend the [p2 garbage collector application](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Equinox/p2/FAQ)

Answer (score 2):

Think bundles ... just do bundle.getResource( clazz.getName().replace('.','/')+".class")

Before you recompile, look in the bundle: "OSGI-OPT/src/" + clazz.getName().replace('.','/')+".java", the actual source code might be there.

Comment: Not only is this more reliable than searching all the jars for a class which may exist in multiple versions, it will be far more efficient.